# STK600 routing & socket for SOIC8 ATtiny85

Tags: avr, atmel, attiny, dip

I just purchased an STK600 (Atmel programmer for AVR8/32b) and a bunch of ATtiny85 chips in a DIP8 package.

The documentation of Atmel is really outdated on the routing and socket cards to use. From what I understood, I choose pick a ATSTK600-RC02 as routing card, and ATSTK600-SC01 as socket card.

Now for my final project, I would like to use the SOIC8 package of my ATtiny85, but I cannot find the proper routing and socket cards to use.

Atmel mapping of chip to routing/socket card does not mention the SOIC8 packages of the ATtiny85, only DIP8. (not to mention all the dead links... (http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/stk600/stk600.introduction_devicesupport.html)

I guess I could take the somehow generic ATSTK600-SC11 as socket card, but its documentation states "SOIC 14/20/24/32", so I am not even sure I will be able to have a proper pinout for my SOIC8 there.
I have some intuition that tells me the ATSTK600-RC46 could be used as routing card, but again the documentation states it is designed for DIP14.

I am really lost here, the documentation from Atmel is full of dead links, I guess because of the move to the microchip website. And there are really little documentation on internet on these chips and how to program them. I am just beginning the direct chip programming, coming from the Arduino world, so since this is a significant investment, I really would not want to buy useless routing/socket cards.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The STK-500 supports the Attiny85 8/20 pin.

I bought my STK-500 well over 10 years ago.

It was very simple and reliable and I never needed support.  I was up and running in minutes.

And it's $88.84 from Digikey

[image]

Comment: The STK500 looks really more reliable, simple, and easier to use, but I (maybe wrongly) assumed it may be outdated or not able to program newer chips.

Comment: @NewbiZ It has a limited number of chips you can plug in to the board.  The programming is an ISP thing which is controlled by AVR Studio.  I see no reason why it would not program newer chips.  But I cannot say for sure because I have not tried. It's a software issue.